# Raspberry Pi 3B: Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B, a 32GB SanDisk Extreme 32GB microSD A1 U3 V30 UHS-I bought from a SanDisk- licensed distributor. I've loaded Raspbian 2020-05-27-raspios-buster-full-armhf.img onto it. I went through the normal boot process, which involves one iteration of the Pi re-sizing the partitions, rebooting, enabling SSH, rebooting, loading lots of software, for a total of 13 reboots before getting to the RPi Desktop. At some point, it ran an update, and rebooted. From then on, I get the message:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I ran fsck (from Ubuntu) on both the partitions, and found no errors on either the boot or rootfs partitions.

```
% sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.74 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf8600252

Device          Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 62333951 61801472 29.5G 83 Linux
```

What the info would be helpful?

Comment: The NOOBS error you mentioned refers to a problem on partition 6 - your error is meaningless; something is seriously wrong, but without more information is unanswerable.

Comment: What info would be helpful?

Comment: "re-sizing the partitions" - is not something I've ever had to do manually ... what is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`

Comment: @Chelmite A detailed list of what YOU did - not just vague statements. This might help to work out what went wrong but it is unlikely to be recoverable.

Comment: obviously you can't do the command I suggested (d'oh) ... what's the output of `fdisk -l /dev/???` in Ubuntu where `???` is the sdcard device

Comment: Pretty sure it's the `(0,0)` part that is wrong -- this refers to the first partition, which is not the root fs.  Edit in the content of `/boot/cmdline.txt`.